# How to get the absolute path to android assets

Tags: java, android, path, libgdx, simple-framework

I'm programming an app for android using libgdx and simplexml to load the levels. Now I want to load the level1.xml file which is located at the android assets file but I don't know how to get the correct path to it. This is my code:

```
private Level currentLevel;

...
loadLevel(1);
...

private void loadLevel(int level) {
    String path = Gdx.files.internal("level" + level +".xml").path();
    try {
        InputStream source = new FileInputStream(path);
        Serializer serializer = new Persister();
        currentLevel = serializer.read(Level.class, source);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But the path I get is just "level1.xml". I know how to do this with

```
InputStrem source = getAssets().open("level1.xml");
```

Because I'm doing this in my core-module I can't use the android libraries and I want use my app on windows/linux/html too.
I hope my question is understandable. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In case of internal (read only, packed with the app, as it seems to be in your question) your files should be located at "project/android/assets", (or "project/core/assets" if not targeting android backend) and you can load them using Gdx.files.internal(), so in this case, it would be

```
Gdx.files.internal("level1.xml")
```

It will return a FileHandle, you can read the content as string directly using

```
Gdx.files.internal("level1.xml").readString();
```

Remember to set the working directory of your desktop project to "project/android/assets"

I recomend you to read the wiki, it explains it very detailed [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling)

Answer (score 0):

You can access file in assets like this 
    "file:///android_asset/level1.xml"